# Clear Toast Notification

Tags: uwp, windows-10

if I call ToastNotificationManager.History.Clear(); to clear notifications, the app freezes for a while (ca. 10 seconds). It takes too long. I tried sample (Notifications) on github. I tested it on Lumia 650. On Lumia 950XL it goes quickly.

Comment: I test the [Notifications](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications) sample on Lumia 640 that it works fine. Have you tested it on the other device? Also please try to reset your device of your Lumia 650.

Comment: I tried to reset the device, but problem still persists.

Comment: So I did factory reset and now it doesn't freeze